# Configure subdomain to point to S3 bucket using Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

How would I go about mapping `files.example.com` to an Amazon S3 bucket using Amazon's Route 53 service? I've attempted to add a CNAME record but I get the following:

[image]

Comment: If you got your screenshot from `files.example.com`, you've done the CNAME setup correctly. That's an AWS permissions error, probably caused by the object you're accessing not being world-readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `CNAME` record for `files.example.com` with content of `s3.amazonaws.com`.

The bucket will need to be named `files.example.com`.

Comment: This is quite old, but nowadays, If the bucket is named after the subdomain (eg both are `files.example.com`) then you can just create an A record with an alias to that bucket, which has many benefits over a CNAME.